Codeigniter failing to load CI_Exceptions
I have an codeigniter 3 app deployed to an ubuntu server.
When one of my models (assumably) hits an error, I am getting this message:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "CI_Exceptions" not found in 
/var/www/application/MyApp/system/core/Common.php:196 Stack trace: #0 
/var/www/application/MyApp/system/core/Common.php(617): load_class() #1 
/var/www/application/MyApp/system/core/Common.php(163): _error_handler() #2 
/var/www/application/MyApp/system/core/Common.php(163): require_once('...') #3 
/var/www/application/MyApp/system/core/Common.php(652): load_class() #4 [internal 
function]: _exception_handler() #5 {main} thrown in 
/var/www/application/MyApp/system/core/Common.php on line 196

This looks to me that the CI_Exceptions class isn't being autoloaded.
I can't see any reason why though, I can see the CI_Exceptions class decalred in the Exceptions.php file located in system/core, the same location as Common.php.
To be clear, my app works. It serves a web page and functions as it should. It's only when an error occurs does this become a problem, since it can't properly raise an exception.
Why would this be happening? I have no way of knowing what the error I'm encountering is. CI is not logging this error to the log file, and my apache log is just the same error message.

Topical content: CodeIgniter not loading extended MY_Exceptions and Codeigniter Rest Server - Fatal error: Class 'CI_Exceptions' not found and Codeigniter 3 show_404 function issue - MY_Exception doesn't load and CodeIgniter does not autoload my core extension

Perhaps your autoloader.  You can run a composer update on the server to recreate the dependency files.
Also, double check that the code is deployed on the server and not just in your local code base.
(I can't just make this a comment bc no rep...)

I don't actually use composer to install codeigniter, I just have a base project folder given to me with all the CI files included. I am definetly running the server code, this is happening on a live web server.
To be clear, my app works. It serves a web page and functions as it should. It's only when an error occurs does this become a problem, since it can't properly raise an exception.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
